# How do I give access to all VPCs via a single VPN on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, vpn, amazon-vpc, aws-devops

The way my set-up works is that I have a 'development', 'staging' and 'production' environment all sitting in separate VPCs and I want to create a client VPN endpoint to allow engineers access to the internals of all these environments (the database mostly).

However, I can't decide how to approach this issue, my first idea was to create a single VPC which peers into all the other VPCs. This would make building the resource in terraform easier as the VPN can be completely separated out.

My other option would be to just have the VPN connection to the development VPC for example and then from there the development VPC peers into the production & staging VPCs however I really don't like this approach

[image: Diagram to access all VPCs from one VPC]

Comment: Have you thought of using a Transit Gateway? [AWS tgw-transit-gateways](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/tgw-transit-gateways.html) Your VPN connection can be attached to it and so can all of your VPCs. The routes can then be used to allow/disallow traffic between the various connections.

Comment: @SteveG Sounds ideal, I'll take a look. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As Steve mentioned from the comment, if you want to centralize your networking setup, for example:

- A single or multi AWS VPN S2S with many VPCs
- A single or multi DX connection with many VPCs
- A single AWS Client VPN to many VPCs
  and more

The answer is **AWS Transit Gateway**. This service also helps you if you have your VPCs placing under different AWS accounts.

For your use-case, AWS has published a blog post with detailed architecture with use-cases for your reference.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-aws-client-vpn-to-scale-your-work-from-home-capacity/

[image: Client VPN to many VPCs]